# Prove that $8(5)^n + 6(3)^{2n} - 80n - 14$ is divisible by $512$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by induction.

Tags: induction, divisibility

Note: question was updated to correct the constant term $-14$ (vs. $-40$).

We need to prove that $8(5)^n + 6(3)^{2n} - 80n - 14$ is divisible by $512$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I started by taking $n = 1$, then for $n = k$ and then for $n = k+1$.

I am stuck here. Not able to solve further but still trying. What to do next?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: $n=1$ was ok, I take it?

Comment: yes it was ok take it

Comment: Ok, now what we usually do for induction is that we show that the difference of the $n$th term and the $(n+1)$th term is divisible by $521$ (which happens to be prime). Did you do this, or did you try something different? Here that difference would be $8(5^{n+1} - 5^n) + 6(3^{2n+2} - 3^{2n}) -80 (n+1 - n)$. So if you show this is divisible by $521$ for all $n$, you are done.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was not able to rearrange properly.

Comment: n=1 gives -26 ... are you convinced this is divisible by 521?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome , but : Is the issue sorted out? I just found the difference of terms?

Comment: sorry, in the question the expression was supposed to be divisible by 512 and i miss tipped it as 521. Thanks for the help

Comment: @VoiletGreen I've edited the question for you.

Comment: You cannot write $n = n + 1$: you need to write $n = k + 1$ instead.

Comment: @VoiletGreen It's still not divisible by $512$. Please check your question again.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Moving target: based on OP's subsequent comment, I edited question to $(512)$.

Comment: @user2661923 I think you forgot to edit the tags. I also forgot about it. Anyway, it should be ([tag:proof-writing]), ([tag:divisibility]), ([tag:induction]).

Comment: If you divide through all the terms by $2$ the second term gives $3^{2n+1}$ which is always odd so the second term is never divisible by $4$, while all the others clearly are. This makes divisibility by $512$ impossible.

Comment: @MarkBennet Something's off : when I made my initial suggestions I was thinking the base case would work out, but it seems the idea of taking successive differences for the induction step was all the OP needed in truth. We still need to ask OP to give the full and correct question, but the underlying concern apparently was something else. Just to confirm, all we can do is say that every term is even, and no more.

Comment: Likely the constant term was meant to be be $-14$ not $-40,\,$ which makes the base case of the induction true - see the linked question. I've edited as such.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Modulo $512$:  $8(4+1)^n+6(8+1)^n\equiv8\left(1+4n+4^2\dfrac{n(n-1)}2\right)+6\left(1+8n+8^2\dfrac{n(n-1)}2\right)\equiv14+80n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in this question we have to prove that difference of $nth$ and $(n+1)th$ term is divisible by 512.

$$ 8(5^{n+1}-5^n)+6(3^{2n+2}-3^{2n})-80(n+1-n) $$ when divided by $512$ gives remainder $0$. Can you continue it now OP?

Also the attempt which you showed in the question in that you cannot write $n=n+1$. You can write it like $n=x+1$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to prove that the difference is divisible by $512$, as the expression is not.

---

For simplicity, let $f(n) = 8(5)^{n} + 6(3)^{2n} - 80n - 40$. We can simplify this as $$f(n) = 8(5)^{n} + 2(3)^{2n + 1} - 40(2n + 1).$$

We are trying to prove that $512$ divides $f(n) - f(n - 1)$. We see that it is

$$\left[8(5)^{n} + 2(3)^{2n + 1} - 40(2n + 1)\right] - \left[8(5)^{n - 1} + 2(3)^{2n - 1} - 40(2n - 1)\right] \\ 8(5)^{n} - 8(5)^{n - 1} + 2(3)^{2n + 1} - 2(3)^{2n - 1} - 40(2n + 1) + 40(2n - 1) \\ 8(5)^{n - 1}(5 - 1) + 2(3)^{2n - 1}(3^{2} - 1) - 80 \\ 32(5)^{n - 1} + 16(3)^{2n - 1} - 80 \\ 16(2(5)^{n - 1} + (3)^{2n - 1} - 5)$$

Because we factored $16$, we see that $512/16 = 32$. Hence, we need to prove that $32$ divides $2(5)^{n - 1} + (3)^{2n - 1} - 5$. Let this expression be $g(n)$.

The condition $n \in \mathbb{N}$ tells us that the base case should be $n = 1$. We see that $g(1) = 0$ which is trivial.

Can you do the inducting step?

Answer (score 0):

soupless gave a good answer, I do think that, for completeness, it would be instructive to elaborate and show that 32 indeed divides $g(n) \doteq [2 \times 5^{n}]+ [3 \times 9^{n}] - 5$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$

This is clearly true for $n=1$. Then to show that $32|g(n)$ for general $n$, it suffices to show that $32|[g(n+1) - g(n)]$. To this end, we use the technique that @soupless used above in his answer, and note the following:

$$g(n+1)-g(n) = (8 \times 5^n) + (24 \times 9^{n})$$ $$ = 8 \times [5^n + (3 \times 9^n)].$$

Then 32 indeed divides $g(n+1)-g(n)$ iff 4 divides $5^n+(3 \times 9^n)$.
But this is easy to see that 4 indeed divides $5^n+3 \times 9^n$; to elaborate, $5^n \equiv_4 1$ and $9^n \equiv_4 1$, so
$5^n+3 \times 9^n$ $\equiv_4$ $1+3 \equiv_4 0$.